# Wijdropdown not working after being hidden

Tags: combobox, modal-dialog, hidden, wijmo

Using Wijmo Open ComponentOne's Dropdown, I tried to place it in a registration form that displays when a button is clicked. This form is inside a jquery modal window.

The problem is that it is not displayed like a wijdropdown inside the form.

I supposed that since is was hidden, then it wasn't part of the DOM and so I added a method in the callback of the function that displayed the modal window; when the modal window finishes displaying, then call the .wijdropdown() on the element. However, it didn't work.

In conclusion: the select tag is not being wijdropdowned...

¿Any recommendations?

Script

```
$(function() {
        // show overlay
        $('#product-slideshow-overlay-trigger').live('click', function() {
          var $registerOverlay = $('#product-slideshow-overlay');
          //left position
          var positionLeft = ($(window).width() - $registerOverlay.width())/2;
          $registerOverlay.css({'left':positionLeft});
          //show mask
          $('#mask').fadeIn();
          $registerOverlay.slideDown(function()
          {
                console.log("Started");
                /**Add WijmoDropdown***/
                $('#estado').wijdropdown(function()
                {
                    console.log("Did the wijdropdown");
                });         
                console.log("Ended");
          });
          return false

        });

    }); // end document ready function
```

Answer (score 1):

Refresh the wijdropdown when the dropdown is not hidden:

```
$('.wijmo_drp').wijdropdown("refresh");
```

or

Find the wijmo component and check if it's visible or not (styled or not).
And trigger the visiblity changed event when you display the modal window.

```
if($('.wijmo-wijobserver-visibility').is(':visible'))
{
$('.wijmo-wijobserver-visibility').trigger("wijmovisibilitychanged");
}
```